# Slideshare-like search box?

Tags: javascript, css

My first post here!
Can anyone please tell me how to create a searchbox effect like that of Slideshare where on click the searchbox changes length with a certain speed and get back to its original size with a certain speed,i.e,not at once,which is what happens with my small code:

```
function long()
{
document.getElementById("GS").style.width="300px";
document.getElementById("submit").style.left="1168px";
}
function back()
{
document.getElementById("GS").style.width="200px";
document.getElementById("submit").style.left="1068px";
}`
```

Comment: Search for `jQuery animations`. http://api.jquery.com/animate/ Also you don't need to change the submit button position. With appropriate
 `floating` it will move itself. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be using jquery animate:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
 top.$('#submit').toggle(function() {
   $(this).animate({ 
     width: 1168
   }, 500);
   },
    function() {
   $(this).animate({ 
     width: 1068
   }, 500);
 });
```